# Acces/See settings page for a custom odule

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I upgraded a module from 5 to 6. I only have one problem:
I can access the settings page for it, but can not see the contents of it.
This is my code:

```
function agbnagscreen_menu() {
  global $user;
  $items = array();

    if (agbnagscreen_nag($user)) {
//       var_dump($_GET['q']); die();
      drupal_goto(sprintf('%s/%s', AGBNAGSCREEN_NAGURL, base64_encode($_GET['q'])));
      die();
    }

    $items['admin/settings/agbnagscreen'] = array(
     // 'path' => 'admin/settings/agbnagscreen',
      'title' => 'AGB nagscreen',
      'access callback' => user_access('Einstellungen von AGB aendern'), 
      //'access' => user_access('Einstellungen von AGB aendern'),
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'callback arguments' => array('agbnagscreen_settings_fapi'),
    );

    $items[AGBNAGSCREEN_NAGURL] = array(
     // 'path' => AGBNAGSCREEN_NAGURL,
      'title' => 'Allgemeine Geschaeftsbedingungen',
      'access' => TRUE,
      'callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'callback arguments' => array('agbnagscreen_fapi'),
      'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
    );

  return $items;
}
```

I think the problem is cause by this line:

```
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
```

Is that correct? How can I write it, that it works?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read through the [Drupal menu system (Drupal 6.x)](http://drupal.org/node/102338) handbook page to understand the changes to the menu system: you have several problems in your `hook_menu` implementation.

1. The conditional at the top will never fire: Drupal 6 only calls `hook_menu()` when the menu is rebuilt, not on every page load.
2. There is no `callback`: use `page callback`.
3. The `page callback` accepts `page arguments`, not `callback arguments`.
4. There is `access`: use `access callback`.
5. `access callback` always a string containing the function name, not a function, and defaults to `"user_access"`: you need to supply `access arguments`.

A modified version of your `hook_menu` implementation might be:

```
function agbnagscreen_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/settings/agbnagscreen'] = array(
    'title' => 'AGB nagscreen',
    'access arguments' => array('Einstellungen von AGB aendern'), 
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('agbnagscreen_settings_fapi'),
  );

  $items[AGBNAGSCREEN_NAGURL] = array(
    'title' => 'Allgemeine Geschaeftsbedingungen',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('agbnagscreen_fapi'),
    'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}
```